# What is example url to get all categories from wordpress json plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress

Is it possible to get all categories from wordpress. I need example url. For example to get recent posts we use:
http://www.example.org/?json=get_recent_posts

But I want to get all categories something like this:

http://www.example.org/?json=get_all_categories

Comment: What have you tried? As stated, this question seems pretty rough to get excited about. It also is pretty hard to answer, given that WordPress supports a variety of permalink formats.

Comment: Hi I updated my question please check now.

Comment: It's a much better question after that edit.

Comment: what is the production url to get all posts from wordpress

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of the plugin:

http://www.example.org/?json=get_category_index